# SOAP message can not parse to java object

Tags: java, xml, soap, jaxb

I have following SOAP message and generated jaxb class.

SOAP Message:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Body>
<ns1:sendSmsResponse xmlns:ns1="http://www.csapi.org/schema/parlayx/sms/send/v2_2/local">
<result>100001200301111029065e4000141</result>
</ns1:sendSmsResponse>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

JAXB class

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "sendSmsResponse", propOrder = {
    "result"
})
public class SendSmsResponse {
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String result;
    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }
    public void setResult(String value) {
        this.result = value;
    }

}
```

But this generated unmarshalling Exception as follows.

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"http://www.csapi.org/schema/parlayx/sms/send/v2_2/local", local:"result"). Expected elements are <{}result> 
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:161)
```

But if I remove `ns1:` from `<ns1:result>`, it will parse. What could be the cause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message tells you that it encountered a result element with a namespace while it expected a result element without a namespace ( the "{}" in <{}result> means no namespace).

You have to specify the namespace to JAXB via the namespace attribute :

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "sendSmsResponse", propOrder = {
    "result"
})
public class SendSmsResponse {
    @XmlElement(required = true,namespace="http://www.csapi.org/schema/parlayx/sms/send/v2_2/local")
    protected String result;
    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }
    public void setResult(String value) {
        this.result = value;
    }

}
```